# Unable to remove all markers in Google Map v3

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, removeall

I am adding makers like this:

```
 var markers = [];
    var map = null;
$.ajax({
        type:"GET",
        dataType:"json",
        url:"<?php echo site_url("sandbox_faizan/get_coordinates") ?>",
        success: function(result)
        {
            for(var i=0;i<result.length;i++)
            {
                var obj = [] ;
                obj.lat=result[i].lat;
                obj.lng=result[i].lng;
                obj.count=result[i].Count;
             //   points.push(new google.maps.LatLng(result[i].lat,result[i].lng));
               markers.push(obj);
                //console.log(points[i]);
                console.log(markers[i]);
            }
            addMarkers();
        }
    });
 function addMarkers() {
        // when the map is initialized and the points have been initialized, add them to the map
        if ((map != null) && (markers.length > 0)) {
            for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
                var marker = new MarkerWithLabel({
                    map: map,
                    position: new google.maps.LatLng(markers[i].lat,markers[i].lng),
                    icon: pinImage,
                    shadow: pinShadow,
                    labelContent: markers[i].count,
                    labelAnchor: new google.maps.Point(12, -5),
                    labelClass: "labels"
                });
                bounds.extend (new google.maps.LatLng(markers[i].lat,markers[i].lng));
                map.fitBounds (bounds);
            }
        }
    }
```

I am clearing markers like this:

```
  function remove_markers(){

        google.maps.Map.prototype.clearMarkers = function() {
            for(var i=0; i < this.markers.length; i++){
                this.markers[i].setMap(null);
                alert("removing now"); // THIS DOES NOT ALERT
            }
            this.markers = new Array();
        };
    }
```

It does nothing, I tried other approaches that uses setMap(null) , previously it gave me error uncaught type error setMap not defined in console.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: console don't log anything?

Comment: Nothing in this case, even the alert does not pop up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var marker = new MarkerWithLabel({
                map: map,
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(markers[i].lat,markers[i].lng),
                icon: pinImage,
                shadow: pinShadow,
                labelContent: markers[i].count,
                labelAnchor: new google.maps.Point(12, -5),
                labelClass: "labels"
            });
markersToRemove.push(marker); // markersToRemove is a global array

function removeMarkers() {
    for(var i = 0; i < markersToRemove.length; i++) {
        markersToRemove[i].setMap(null);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you , you were quite fast at figuring out the issue.

Comment: but this wont clear the marker in javascript memory.

Comment: Using your above code I get `Uncaught ReferenceError: removeMarkers is not defined`. What does this mean?

Comment: @dj_cd you please paste a link with your script

Answer (score 2):

You markers array is not a property of the google.maps.Map object (unless you are using a library that does that). The way your code adds them, they are in a global array named "markers".

But that isn't an array of google.maps.Marker objects, you need to keep references to those markers.

```
 var gmarkers = [];
 function addMarkers() {
        // when the map is initialized and the points have been initialized, add them to the map
        if ((map != null) && (markers.length > 0)) {
            for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
                var marker = new MarkerWithLabel({
                    map: map,
                    position: new google.maps.LatLng(markers[i].lat,markers[i].lng),
                    icon: pinImage,
                    shadow: pinShadow,
                    labelContent: markers[i].count,
                    labelAnchor: new google.maps.Point(12, -5),
                    labelClass: "labels"
                });
                bounds.extend (new google.maps.LatLng(markers[i].lat,markers[i].lng));
                gmarkers.push(marker);
                map.fitBounds (bounds);
            }
        }
    }
```

Then this should remove them (and be very annoying with lots of markers).

```
  function remove_markers(){
     for(var i=0; i < gmarkers.length; i++){
       gmarkers[i].setMap(null);
       alert("removing now"); // THIS DOES NOT ALERT
     }
     gmarkers = [];
  };
```

Comment: Yes your solution also works fine :) Can you explain if i don't add this gmarkers[]; at end, it still clears the markers. whats the difference in using it or not?

Comment: `gmarkers[i].setMap(null);` clears the markers from the map. `gmarkers = []` deletes the markers from the array - no more markers.

Comment: Which means that if I want to add new markers again after clearing the old ones, then I should clear them from the array too ?

Comment: If you want to reuse the same markers on the map again, don't clear the array. If you want all-new markers to appear on the map, clear the array.

Comment: If you don't remove them from the array (use the gmarkers = []), then they will keep accumulating in the array as you add new ones.  Not a problem if you are only adding them then hiding them, but it will waste memory if you do it lots and if you want to hide and redisplay markers it will increase the processing time (and lead to unexpected behavior).

Answer (score 1):

1) You're adding the wrong information to markers. You need to add it after the marker has been declared:

First, rename your markers array to `markersData`.

Then ensure that your markers array is getting each marker.

```
var marker = new MarkerWithLabel({
  // stuff
});

markers.push(obj);
```

Then try it without calling that prototype:

```
function remove_markers() {
  for(var i=0; i < this.markers.length; i++){
    markers[i].setMap(null);
    alert("removing now");
  }
  this.markers = new Array();
}
```

Note that `this.markers = new Array();` or `this.markers.length = 0;` will destroy the markers array and they won't exist anymore. If you just want to remove the markers from the map, just do:

```
function remove_markers() {
  for(var i=0; i < this.markers.length; i++){
    markers[i].setMap(null);
    alert("removing now");
  }
}
```

The markers will still be in the array and you can add them back to the map whenever you want.

I'm not sure, but I think the `fitbounds` statement should be outside the loop, but I might be wrong.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/andyuws/Vw55H/1/)

Comment: I think @edotassi is right, cause I tried your code Andy , and it gives me this error at console, "Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Array] has no method 'setMap' ". How do I resolve this?

Comment: I've amended my answer.

Comment: Thank you, now every1 is figured out the correct solution, it's hard for me to decide who to give best answer :P